# the system doesn't read .bashrc and .profile of a user in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: bash, permissions, bashrc, bash-history, useradd

Recently I added a new user to linux 14.04, `user2`, but the home directory of `user2` is NOT in `/home/user2`, I've put it in different place, lets call it `home2`.

```
useradd -d home2 user2
```

I already had an user, called `user1`, the home directory of `user1` is `/home/user1`, lets call it `home1`.

I've copied `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash-history` from `home1` to `home2`

```
cd home1
cp .bashrc .profile .bash-history home2
```

When I start a session with `user2`, it looks like the system doesn't read the previous files, because the prompt of the shell looks `($)`, it should be look like `(user2@mashinename$)`, and I can't search in the shell history of `user2`, because when I pause the keys button I got nothing but things like `(^[[A ^[[B ^[[C ^[[D)`.

The strange thing is when I start a session with `user1`, then I switch to `user2`, the system reads the previous files of `user2`!

Does any one knows what the problem is?.

Comment: Whats the output of `ls "$(awk -F: '/user2/ {print $6}' /etc/passwd)"/.bash*`?, replace `user2` with the actual username.

Comment: What are the permissions of the copied files?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I forgot to change the owner of the copied files.
also i change the environment of user2 from the default (sh) to bash, that solved the history problem.